# With y End with con IF, es posible? vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Es posible realizar un if con la sentencia With en vb.net?
Teniendo el siguiente codigo a resumir:

```
if variable then   
  with variable
     ... ... ... 
     (código repetido)
     ... ... ...    
  end with 
else
   with variable2
      ... ... ...
      (código repetido)
      ... ... ...   
   end with 
end if
```

en este caso, se puede ver que el código se repite dos veces, y la idea seria simplificar tal caso, por ejemplo algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
with if variable then variable or variable2
... ... ...
(codigo)
... ... ...
end with
```

en el With que se pueda agilizar diferenciando la variable por una condición? espero que puedan responderme muchas gracias

PD: un ejemplo para demostrar un poco mejor el codigo...

```
with textbox1 
      .text = "felicidades"
end with

with label1
     .text="felicidades"
end with
```

En este ultimo ejemplo se puede apreciar que para ambos sirve, porque comparten la propiedad TEXT.

Comment: Por qúe no  puso el código repetido en un function() o sub() y usar parametros?

Comment: No, no se puede, el bloque interno siempre esta referido a propiedades de la variable referenciada en el with. La alternativa es hacer lo que te indicó Pikoh.

Answer (score 0):

Sería mucho mas sencillo que uses una tercera variable:

```
Dim variable3 as Boolean = If(variable, variable, variable2)
with variable3
.....
(codigo)
.....
end with
```

Comment: El problema es que seria crear mas variables, y la idea es utilizar la variable, y en algunos casos puede que sea de diferente tipo, por ejemplo label y textbox ambos tienen la propiedad .Text, y puedo compartir esta misma propiedad...

Comment: @BernardoHarreguy Hace mucho que no uso vb.net,pero creo que en ese caso la solución sería crear una variable de tipo `Control`, y hacer un `Select Case` para asignar a dicha variable el control que quieras. Asi podrías acceder a la propiedad `Text` de esta variable auxiliar. Otra opción sería crear un metodo con el codigo comun,y que dicho método recibiera una variable de tipo `Control`